# How can I open a .xv file?

Tags: image-processing, matlab

How can I open a .xv file (Khoros Visualization Image) in Matlab?

Comment: found http://vision.ece.ucsb.edu/texture/software/matlab/loadimg.m

Comment: No it doesnt.. but I think it should be similar..

Comment: I would like to test a function. Can you post your image here?

Comment: You can download the images from http://www.cse.oulu.fi/CMV/TextureClassification . Please let me know if it works for you.

Comment: I've found a [MATLAB code](http://www.ux.uis.no/~tranden/matlab_library/imgwrite.m) but it didn't works. There are some dependencies which I couldn't find. Basically, it converts a `VIFF/XV` image to `TIFF`, then it converts it to another format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems it works only for the images I mentioned. (first one KB contains some other related information and then the image data)

```
                   function d = loadimg(fn)
                      fid = fopen(fn,'r');
                      data = fread(fid);
                      fclose(fid);

                      d = data(1025:end);
                      d = reshape(d, 64,64);
                   end
```

Thanks for the help..